# Как лучше расставить знаки препинания в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

*Депутат Заксобрания Петербурга Оксана Дмитриева отметила, что кластеры – или как их называли в советское время, производственно-территориальные комплексы, – идея не новая.*

Как правильнее расставить знаки внутри предложения? Это цитата, изменить не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Депутат Заксобрания Петербурга Оксана Дмитриева отметила, что кластеры, или, как их называли в советское время, производственно-территориальные комплексы, — идея не новая.**

В этом предложении слова "или производственно-территориальные комплексы" — это пояснительная конструкция, присоединенная союзом *или* (в значении «то есть»).
Такие конструкции обычно выделяются запятыми.

Слова "как их называли в советское время" — это вводное предложение. Вводные конструкции тоже обычно выделяются запятыми.

В Нацкорпусе во всех примерах, содержащих слова "или, как их называли", запятые расставлены по одной схеме:

> Бездельники, или, как их называли раньше, преступники, могли унести деньги и из дома. [Я. Ларри. Страна счастливых (1931)]

Тире обычно ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, когда оба выражены существительным в именительном падеже (у вас: *кластеры — идея*)